# How to add an object to an existing group from Python?

Tags: python, groups

I'm trying to add objects to previously created groups from a Python script.

What do I do?

Answer (score 4):

It is actually pretty simple:

```
import bpy

grp = bpy.data.groups.get('bacon')

obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
grp.objects.link(obj)
```

This avoid the hassle of setting up the context for `bpy.ops` operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

1. Make the desired object active
2. Assign it to an existing group

   ```
   bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Your Object']
   bpy.ops.object.group_link(group='Your Group')
   ```

Comment: It's better to not use operators in Python scripts, if possible. See Mutant Bob's answer to see how it can also be done.